# Prioritize label rendering

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, rendering, vector-layer

It seems that by default, vector layer labels only render after everything else is loaded.

Some wms/wmts feeds being very slow, this means you have to wait for a while before you can see your labels, even though they're local data and as light as text gets.

Is there a way to prioritize them so they display at the same time as vector points, lines and polygons or should I issue a feature request on github?